# Cartographer Unlock A Map

Tags: temple-run-2

Does anyone know how to Unlock A Map/complete the Cartographer objective? I have completed all other challenges but can't seem to complete this one.

Answer (score 4):

To unlock a map, simply tap <kbd>Map</kbd> at the bottom of the screen in the menu, and using gems (500), unlock a map.

If you have already unlocked a level, the achievement will automatically unlock in the objective screen after the next run you complete.